# JS. Внутренняя память

Tags: javascript, выделение-памяти

Сколько байтов в куче занимает объявление функции в JS?

Comment: в зависимости от реализации.

Comment: @Grundy, для Node.js сколько будет?

Comment: Можно попробовать посчитать по [определению класса `Function`](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-4.8/d4/da0/v8_8h_source.html#l03181)